# What is the mathematical formula to determine this lease rent re-negotiation?

Tags: contract-law, lease

> The total annual rental for each such period for said land shall be equal to the prevailing rate of interest then charged by responsible lending institutions in the community for private loans on the security of real estate and the then market value of the demised land, exclusive of all improvements there on, as determined by appraisal.

Assignable apartment lease in condominium project dates back to 1967 and describes this one time renegotiation of the lease rent that occurs May 25, 2020.

What does the “and” mean or how does it function?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because that's not a math formula, it is an order to have the land assessed. Either way, it's not about the law.

Comment: The lease sounds non-sensical to me now but when I purchased the apartment by assignment of the lease I thought I understood it.  What does it say?  It’s a contract law question.

Comment: it says "average interest rate for private people on the value of the land alone - have that appraised"

Comment: If the "prevailing rate of interest" is x % and the "then market value" is y $, then the annual rent shall be (x*y)/100 $ seems to be the only reasonable interpretation of the "and" (though better connectives would be prefered, e.g., "multiplied by" or "applied to"). For clearly it is not possile for one thing A to be equal to both thing B and thing C unless B=C.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen In some contexts, "A is equal to B and C" means "A is equal to B+C", but that doesn't seem to apply here.

Comment: This is about the meaning of a legal document, specifically a lease. I think that makes it on-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

The structure of the sentence is clearer if you remove some of the modifiers: it reduces to saying "The rent shall be equal to the interest rate on real estate and the market value of the land exclusive of improvements". The intent of "and" is apparently "plus" rather than "and" (in the sens "both A and B must be true"). If I say "The rent is equal to $5 and $2", that has a ridiculous interpretation (5 is not equal to 2 so the rent cannot be equal to both $5 and to $2), and a believable interpretation ("the rent is equal to $5 *plus* $2". Recall from grade school that 5 *and* 2 is 7. The clause has to have some meaning, and while "5 and 2 is 7" is grade school language, there is no more-sophisticated linguistic interpretation consistent with the words used here.

The interpretation of "and" as "plus" is not the only issue. Let's say that the prevailing loan interest rate is 3%, and let's say that the market sale value of the land is $100,000. The sentence seems to say that the rent is $100,000 plus 3%. It's meaningless to literally add "3%" to some number: you have to add 3% *of* something (the land sale value?). However, if you say to a person "you have to pay me this amount, plus 3%", one normally would interpret that as meaning "this amount, plus 3% *of this amount*". The stiff legalese suggests legal precision, the lax use of "and" and adding a dollar amount to an interest rate suggests great linguistic imprecision. Whether or not it is patently ridiculous to charge the market value of the land (and therefore could not be reasonably held to be what was agreed to) cannot be judged from the sentence alone. "Market value" is at least ambiguous as to "value of the land *as rental property*" and "*sale* value of the land". The more likely interpretation is "value of the land as rental property": I sure would not pay $100,000 per year to rent my house.